# Communicating between two windows Qt5

Tags: c++, qt5

I have a main window where I will draw something on it and it will instantly display the drawing at an another window. The problem right now I am facing is what is the best way get both of these windows to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you started the window in the same program, you can pass a pointer to the other window and save that:

In MyWindowOne:

```
include "mywindow2.h"

class MyWindowOne {

MyWindowTwo * p_window_two;

}
```

The same for the other window. You can now use these pointers to manipulate the windows from the other window class.

In MyWindow2.h:

```
class MyWindowTwo {

friend class MyWindowOne;

...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried your suggestion above. However I'm still unable to trigger my PaintEvent() on the second window. Any suggestions ?

Comment: How are you calling it? If you have auto-generated headers (from .ui-files), you have to include those as well.

Comment: e.g. #include "mywindow2.h"
#include "ui_mywindow2.h"

Comment: Oh. You also have to declare it as a friend class, of course. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on what are you doing and how you are doing.

The easiest way is to use two QGraphivsView and share the same QGraphivsScene() between them.

A second approach is to trigger an update() on the second window, and on the paintEvent draw a QPixmap on it, this pixmap should be the first widget's pixmap.

Both will work.